# Evaluate $\int _{-\infty}^\infty\int _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik(y-x)}}{k^2-m^2}dxdk$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

If I were supposed to evaluate the following Integral

$$
\int _{-\infty}^\infty\int _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik(y-x)}}{k^2-m^2}dxdk
$$
I would supposedly substitute $y-x$ to $z$, and then integrate over $z$ to get a delta function of $k$ and then set $k$ to zero. 
$$
\int _{-\infty}^\infty\int _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-e^{ikz}}{k^2-m^2}dzdk
=
\int _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-2\pi\delta(k)}{k^2-m^2}dk
=\frac{2\pi}{m^2}
$$
My question is this mathematically correct?

Comment: your initial integral is divergent due to singularities at $k=\pm m$, so as long as you don't explain how to hande this issue (cauchy principle part, ...) everything you have done so far is completly meaningless

Comment: That's true good that you pointed that out. But if I do the integration over $x$ before $k$ I avoid that problem right?